# Windows 8/RT + Phone 8 app - sync data

Tags: azure, windows-8, synchronization, windows-phone-8

Hi im developing a todo/reminder app for both Windows 8 (RT) and Windows Phone 8.
I want to enable the user to sync their todo-items between these two.

I know there is a roaming application data storage for Windows 8, but is it possible to access it from the phone?
Another idea i had was creating an xml file and uploading it to skydrive, but then i would have no push functionality :(
And there is also Azure which seems to be the most complicated solution..

What way is the best to choose?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Live SDK (SkyDrive)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/) and [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) to accomplish this.  The Live SDK will allow you to upload and retrieve items from SkyDrive and you can use mobile services for push notifications.  [Here is an example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Event-Buddy-ddafd9b6) of what you want to do.

Comment: You can use Mobile Services to store your data as well, as long as it is in tabular form, which it is by the sound of the question. You shouldn't have to use SkyDrive for this scenario. Check out [this code sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/doto-a-simple-social-todo-7e6ba464).

Answer (score 1):

I know that the thread is a bit old, but it still pops up in search results. So, here's the answer.

I had exactly the same problem. So, I have developed a small library which does exactly that - synchronizing the data between Windows Phone and Windows Azure. Code is on [GitHub](http://bit.ly/ProjectMirror) and here is a nicely packed [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ProjectMirror/) package. You could easily port it to WinRT and use SQLite as local data storage.

API is very simple. You just call methods to do CRUD operations and when you are done, you call `SynchronizeAsync` to synchronize data with WAMS. The synchronization goes both ways. In case of conflict, the latest copy gets the preference.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime Windows Phone 8.1 is released and it changes the answer to your question - today there are universal apps and they share the same roaming storage on both Phone and regular Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use Mobile Services (www.windowsazure.com/mobile) for this scenario.  After you login at manage.windowsazure.com, grab the WinStore C# SDK and WP8 SDK.  You're going to need to point both to the same SQL db and Mobile Service. Of course, if you need blob or table storage as well, that's supported. You'd just access those through scripts under the DATA tab.

To check out a production app that's already doing this, I'd point your to Slot Machine by the SeeSharpGuys.
Win Store: http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/slot-machine/7c60012a-00bd-4cae-a402-a9885ec11ea1
WP8: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/slot-machine-mobile/9fa24191-d08d-4073-8098-740975e41946